# Having trouble calling my usage method when there is no arguments on the command line in a compression and decompression program

Tags: java

Having trouble calling my usage method when there is no arguments on the command line in a compression and decompression program. When I run the program without any arguments I need to call my usage method.

```
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Set;

/**
* 
* 
*/

 public class Compress {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "aaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb";
    String output = "";

    //Compress the input
    output = compress(input);
    System.out.println("Compressed string:" + output + "\n");

    //Decompress the above output and verify if the decompressed string matches input.
    System.out.println("       Input String: " + input);
    output = decompress(output);
    System.out.println("Decompressed String: " + output + "\n");

    if (input.equals(output)) {
        System.out.println("Compression & Decompression happened successfully");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Compressions (or) Decompression failed");
    }
}

/**
 * Compress the input string.
 */
public static String compress(String input) {
    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
    char[] inputArray = input.toCharArray();

    //Preserves the order of characters in the string, and, at the same time keeps track of count of each character.
    //It's like if 'a' occurs 10 times, 'b' occurs 36 times, map will have in order, ('a', 10) & ('b', 36) like that.
    LinkedHashMap<Character, Integer> map = new LinkedHashMap<Character, Integer>();

    //Construct the map and set the count for each character.
    for(Character character: inputArray) {
        if (true == map.containsKey(character)) {
            map.put(character, map.get(character) + 1);
        } else {
            map.put(character, 1);
        }
    }


    Set<Character> set = map.keySet();
    for(Character character:set) {      
        //Below statement, if commented out, gives count of each Character in Input. (For debugging purposes)
        //System.out.println(character + ":" + map.get(character));

        //create the compressed string for each Entry in the map and append it to the final output.
        //That is if an entry is ('a', 9) it returns 'a9' which gets appended to the final output.
        output.append(encodeCountToString(character, map.get(character)));
    }

    return output.toString();
}

/*
 * Encodes each character run
 * That is if an entry is ('a', 9) it returns 'a9' which gets appended to the final output.
 */
public static String encodeCountToString(Character character, int count) {
    String output = "";

    if (count >0 && count <=9) {
        //Deals with the case of count is 0-9
        output = character.toString() + Integer.toString(count);
    } else if (count > 9 && count <= 35) {
        //Deals with the case of count 10-35 (Outputs 'A'(~10 count)-'Z'(~35 count)
        //that is if 'a' appeared 10 times, output will be "aA"
        output = character.toString() + (char) ('A' + (count - 9) - 1);
    } else if (count > 35 && count <=61) {
        //Deals with the case of count 36-61 (Outputs 'a'(~36 count)-'z'(~61 count)
        //that is if 'a' appeared 37 times, output will be "ab"
        output = character.toString() + (char) ('a' + (count - 35) - 1);
    } else if (count > 61) {
        //If the count is more than 61, append the 'z' and recursively solve for the extra count.
        //that is if 'a' appeared 62 times, output will be "aza1"
        output = character.toString() + 'z' + encodeCountToString(character, count - 61);
    }

    return output;
}

//Decompress the compressed string
public static String decompress(String input) {
    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
    char[] inputArray = input.toCharArray();
    int inputArrayLength = inputArray.length;

    Character character = ' ';
    int characterCount = 0;

    //Read 2 characters at a time from the input string.
    for(int i = 0; i < inputArrayLength; i = i + 2) {
        character = inputArray[i];

        //Get the count from the second character of the pair.
        characterCount = decodeCharacterToCount(inputArray[i+1]);

        //Below statement, if commented out, gives count of each Character in compressed string. (For debugging purposes)
        //System.out.println(character.toString() + ":" + characterCount);

        //Add 'character', 'characterCount' times to the Output.
        for (int j = 0; j < characterCount; j++) {
            output.append(character);
        }   
    }

    return output.toString();
}

//turn a character to count according to rules.
//that is, 1-9 ~ 1-9, A-Z to 10-35, a-z to 36-61
public static int decodeCharacterToCount(Character character) {
    int count = 0;

    if (Character.isDigit(character)) {
        count = Integer.parseInt(character.toString());         
    } else if (Character.isUpperCase(character)) {
        count = 9 + character - 'A' + 1;
    } else if (Character.isLowerCase(character)) {
        count = 35 + character - 'a' + 1;
    }

    return count;
}

public static void usage() {
{   //Usage here
    System.out.println("usage: [-d|-m] x1 y1 z1 x2 y2 z2");
    System.exit(0);
}
```

}

Comment: What errors are you getting exactly? Whats the problem?

Comment: You've told us about your code, but haven't actually asked a question related to it - can you clarify what you're trying to ask?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check whether or not any arguments were passed in from the command line. If not, call `usage()`, otherwise proceed as usual:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    if (args.length == 0) {
        usage();
    } else {

        // do what you need to do with the arguments passed in

    }
}
```